# Html Web Pack Plugin inject hash css into html

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I am trying to inject css file into my index.html. Currently my web pack does the following

1. Converts my SASS into CSS
2. Name the css file with hash (e.g. optionA-32d6cb.css)
3. Places into ./dist folder

output of the folder structure:

```
- Dist
   - OptionA
        - optionA-hash.css

   - OptionB
        - optionB-hash.css

   - index.html //How to inject above css into this file?
```

I am new to **HtmlWebpackPlugin** my question is how do i inject above dynamic css files into the index.html? so that in the head section i have the following:

```
<link href="optionA-32d6cb.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="optionB-w2d6cb.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

My webpack.config.js file:

```
module.exports ={
entry: ['path_to_scss_file'],// SASSfile which contains import statment with wildcard to get all sass in given directory
output: {
    filename: "[name].min.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/'),
},
plugins:[
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/index.html'
    })
],
module:{
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options:{
                        name:'[name]/[name]-[contenthash].css',
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options: {
                      sassOptions: {
                             importer: globImporter(), 
                     //my sass files uses wildcard to import all sass files
                      },
                     },
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [webpack-manifest-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-manifest-plugin) to solve this issue which will create a manifest.json file inside the dist/ folder.

The manifest.json file will contain all the mappings like this

```
{
    "app.css": "css/app.dc4d6b6c65b4f5ff351e.css"
}
```

and then use [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/), it will do the job every time you build, it will inject the correct files to `index.html` by referring to `manifest.json`

Refer https://github.com/anandgupta193/react-enterprise-starter-kit for an exact working implementation in webpack/webpack.common.config.js file. (use node 12.x to create a build in the starter kit)

[image]

Note: Remove your scripts and link tags from the index.html template, it will get injected automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, how is the manifest.json file linked to the index.html. I dont see it on your code that part? i am able to generate the manifest on the dist which contains the reference as shown on your answer but its not linked to the index.html

Comment: HtmlWebpackPlugin automatically injects all assets (e.g. bundle.js, main.css) with the correct HTML tags.
Please remove all scripts and link tags from your template HTML (refer: public/index.html in react-enterprise-starter-kit)
Also, try to put inject: true option in your HtmlWebpackPlugin config object.

Comment: Still not working, can you try taking a look at my work please i created a link for you https://www.dropbox.com/t/kq47CfdoXAH0yW7G

Comment: There was an issue with the way you were processing your SCSS files. Scss files will need SCSS loader and CSS loader to finally convert it to CSS. Also, we need ExtractCssChunks plugin for properly creating CSS chunks. Please refer: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3cr4d40z9nkc1km/webpack-demo-solved.zip?dl=0
Please have a look at the code and let me know if this issue is solved.

Comment: Excellent work Anand thank you so much this is alot better but i want the css not to be combined into one? how can i have css per file name so its app.css and legacy.css? it should match based on the sass filenames?

Comment: Please try putting 

"entry": {
        appFile: AppFiles,
        LegacyFile: LegacyFiles
    },

in your webpack.config.js to get separate files. That means instead of an array make it object with key-value pair as shown.

Comment: Excellent thank you Anand :)  I assume i cannot prevent the js being generated from out the output i.e. App.js and Legacy.js or even have the js as a combine file, whilst having the css files seperated

Comment: Unfortunately, that is currently not possible by design. webpack started as a JavaScript bundler which is capable of handling other "web modules", such as CSS and HTML. JavaScript is chosen as the base language because it can host all the other languages simply as strings. I guess we have solved the base problem which was asked as part of this question, you can mark this answer as correct and maybe post another question which does not relates to this. I hope you have got some help to get going. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The value of `entry` should be a path to a .js file: [docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/)

And I recommend to use [mini-css-extract-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/).
It will extract your CSS into separate files

Then your webpack.config could look like this:

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './main.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, './index.html'),
    }),
  ],
};
```

`main.js`

```
import './style.scss';
```

`style.scss`

```
body {
  background: #fefefe;
}
```

If you want your css files in a special path in your `/dist` folder, you can define [options](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/#options) for the plugin

Comment: This wouldnt work for me because i am using globbing in my sass file to import all sass in given directory. I am currently using GlobImporter in my sass-loader, the above would fail as it wouldnt respect the wildcard (*)

Comment: You could replace your glob import with webpack's require.context: https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext

Then this setup works and you don't have to explizit import every file

Comment: Do you have an example of how to achieve this because i am new to webpack and not exactly sure how do i use this context as part of the webpack config

Comment: with require.context, you can import all you .scss files inside your script e.g.:

`main.js`
```
const context = require.context('./styles', false, /\.scss$/);
```

Comment: With `require.context` you can import all `.scss` inside you script:

`main.js`

`const context = require.context('./styles', false, /\.scss$/);
context.keys().map(context);`

here is also an example: https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#context-module-api